# Firebase database rules: Use variable before it is declared in the database path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am working on a Firebase app where users ("students") just have access to some courses (these courses are declared in the users parts of the database).
Every user needs to have access to "courses" in the database, but I cannot give general read rules to this path, because it will overwrite any deeper path security rules as well.

I tried to just use the Firebase rule I used at "courses/$course_id" for "courses", but it does not work because the variable "$course_id" is not declared at this point.

My Firebase database structure for "courses" is as following:

```
  "courses" : {
   "76g" : {
    "questions" : {
     "123h9014bsd" : true,
     "56a" : {
      "firstWrongAnswer" : "B",
      "question" : "A",
      "rightAnswer" : "A",
      "secondWrongAnswer" : "C"
    }
  },
    "title" : "Course1"
}
```

These are the Firebase rules I wrote to achieve what I described above:

```
"courses": {
//error for the following line: Error saving rules - Line 9: Unknown variable '$course_id'.
  ".read": "root.child('students').child(auth.uid).child('courses').hasChild($course_id)",
  "$course_id": {
    ".read": "root.child('students').child(auth.uid).child('courses').hasChild($course_id) 
  }
}
```

Can this problem even be changed by just using Firebase database rules or do I need to change my database structure?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate read rules? And is the second one giving any errors?

Comment: If students should only have access to a specific course, you cannot ensure that with a rule on `/courses`. But it  is not clear to me what the problem is. If you remove the `.read` rule from `/courses`, which read operation in your app fails?

Comment: @AndréKool I wanted to show that I need the second rule at "/courses", but that doesn't work because of the variable. The second one works fine.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I need read access at "/courses" because all the courses are observed from my iOS app.

Comment: @OSX55 Why don't you just give all students read access to courses? ".read": "root.child('students').hasChild(auth.uid)"